# jackson - read specific field from string list of jsons

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

I'm pretty new to world of jackson, and wanted to read the value of specific field from **list of jsons** (which is a response body of third-party api).

for a single json, using `objectMapper` works fine.

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(sampleString);
        JsonNode idNode = rootNode.path("id");
        System.out.println("id: "+ idNode.asText());
```

But I want to parse **list of jsons** (which is a string coming from a response body)
.So for example I receive this body:

```
[  
{  
  "id":10,
  "firstName":"Jack",
  "primaryPhone":"9999999999",
  "email":"jack@me.com"
},
{  
  "id":4,
  "firstName":"Mark",
  "primaryPhone":"9999999991",
  "email":"mark@me.com"
},
{  
  "id":12,
  "firstName":"Susaan",
  "primaryPhone":"9999999992",
  "email":"susan23@me.com"
}
]
```

I want to read the  `id`s first, and if I find a specific id, return some other info from that block.

For example if `id=4`, read the `firstName` and `email` of that person.

But I'm not sure how to parsee list of json.

Any suggestions/comments is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

```
JsonNode array = objectMapper.readValue(sampleString, JsonNode.class);
 for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    JsonNode jsonNode = array.get(i);
    JsonNode idNode = jsonNode.get("id");
    String id = idNode.asText();
    if(id.equals("4")){
        JsonNode firstNameNode = jsonNode.get("firstName");
        String firstName = firstNameNode.asText();
        System.out.println("firstName = " + firstName);
        JsonNode emailNode = jsonNode.get("email");
        String email = emailNode.asText();
        System.out.println("email = " + email);
        break;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Json Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

So, the query would be something like this:

```
$[?(@.id == 4)].firstName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a POJO like the one below:

```
class Record {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

And deserialise the `json` into `List` of these POJOS, e.g.:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Record> records = mapper.readValue("", new TypeReference<List<Record>>() { });
```

Once done, you can filter out the records with `stream`, e.g.:

```
List<Record> filtered = records.stream()
    .filter(r -> r.getId() = 12)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```